# PHP Check to AJAX Check

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I currently have the following code written in PHP but I am unsure what the best way is to  change it to an ajax request.  I am wanting to create an alert if the model is `> 0`

I am very new to ajax so I am very unsure on how to attack this and I know that I need to change the following to:

```
$post['post_title'] = #post_title
$website_id = {website_id}
```

**PHP:**

**Controller:**

```
$urlCheck = $this->page_model->pageURLCheck($post['post_title'],  website_id);

        if($urlCheck > 0)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Page Title Exists', 'error');       
        }else{
            $save_success = $this->page_model->save($post, $action, $post_id);
        }
```

**Model:**

```
function pageURLCheck($title, $id)
{
    $this->db->select('post_title', 'website_id');
    $this->db->where('post_title', $title);
    $this->db->where('website_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table['posts']);
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: How you navigate to your current controller (url) ?]

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 Via a web browser :P `admin/websites/{website_id}/page/op/{$action}/{$id}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may help you:

```
$(function(){
    $(".parent_div_id").on('click', '#this_id', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           url      : '<?=base_url()?>/controller_name/function_name',
           data     : { post_title : $("#post_title").val(), 'website_id' : $("#website_id").val() },
           type     : 'POST',
           success  : function(resp){
                alert( resp );
           },
           error    : function(resp){
                console.log("Error in ajax request");
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Your controller changes:

```
if($urlCheck > 0)
{
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'Page Title Exists', 'error');
    echo "Page Title Exists";       
}else{
    $save_success = $this->page_model->save($post, $action, $post_id);
    echo "Saved successfully";
}
```

Hope it helps you. :D